# Linearly scaling a distribution (X) to have the same 5th and 95th percentile of distribution (Y)

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, quantiles, linear

As done in this paper [here:](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2164/15/154/figure/F5)

I would like to linearly scale a distribution such that it has the same 5th and 95th percentile (0.05 and 0.95 quantile) as another distribution.

That is, given two genes on two different platforms, how do I scale them to have the same 5th and 95th % percentile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the 5th percentile of $X$ is $l_x$ and the 95th percentile is $u_x$, and similarly for $Y$.

You now want to construct a linear transformation $Z=aX+b$ such that $l_z = l_y$ and $u_z=u_y$.

Note that $\frac{X-l_x}{u_x-l_x}$ has the required percentiles at 0 and 1.

Hence $Z=l_y+(u_y-l_y)\frac{X-l_x}{u_x-l_x}$ should match those percentiles with $Y$.

Here's an example in R:

```
 x=rnorm(100)
 y=rgamma(100,3,.2)

 quantile(x,c(.05,.95))
       5%       95% 
-1.685679  1.517378 

 quantile(y,c(.05,.95))
       5%       95% 
 4.724867 29.434846 

 lx=quantile(x,.05)
 ux=quantile(x,.95)
 ly=quantile(y,.05)
 uy=quantile(y,.95)
 z=ly+(uy-ly)*(x-lx)/(ux-lx)

 quantile(z,c(.05,.95))
       5%       95% 
 4.724867 29.434846
```

Comment: Correlation is not affected at all by linear rescaling. If that code snippet is *actually* what they do, it would be wrong.

Comment: Looking at the code (unless I am looking at the wrong place), I don't think your code exactly represents what they did.

Comment: Is it possible you update your answer to cover what they implemented. This is my end goal.

Comment: @David As far as I can see, what they did is what I say above.

Comment: I have 100 samples measured on two platforms, which is what I have implemented this linear transformation on. I have an additional 900 samples on one array, is it possible to also transform this data even though it doesn't have matched samples? How would I do this? The paper mentions the following:

'We performed this scaling strategy using only samples from brain 2, and reserved brain 1 as an independent test set.'

Comment: It's not clear to me how you'd match the quantiles without a corresponding set to match them to, but maybe there's something about the situation you understand that I do not (I know nothing of the application area). It's also not clear to me how your last sentence relates to what precedes it.

Comment: I expect the 100 samples to have the same/similar distribution as the larger set.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not in a position of sufficient understanding of the situation to say something sensible.